# Ionic: how to deal with automatic updates of an offline app?

Tags: ionic-framework, offlineapps

I'm designing an Ionic app which works offline, periodically sync'ing with the server.
It will have local storage in SQLite.

But if the app is automatically updated with local data that hasn't yet been sync'ed, that data may be lost, right?

My question is how to guarantee that the data will be sync'ed before any eventual automatic updates? Or if there are specific guidelines to deal with this issue..

Comment: I'm not sure that local data is purged when the app updates. Have you confirmed this?

Comment: No, I haven't. It's just a fear I had.

Comment: Data won't be lost if the app got updated automatically. It still persist in the DB, unless you have renamed the database name.

Comment: great, thanks guys